# How do I center the contents of a webview in iOS vertically and horizontally?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, webview

I have googled quite a bit and I can't seem to find anything that makes sense to me. I need to center the contents of a webview both vertically and horizontally. I have been able to get the horizontal to work with this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *bodyStyle = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign = 'center';";
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyle];
}
```

But I can't find anything on vertical. Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm fond of this quote on Vertical centering:
The easiest way to vertically center something in CSS is to close your laptop and go to the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
NSString *bodyStyleVertical = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.verticalAlign = 'middle';";
NSString *bodyStyleHorizontal = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign = 'center';";
NSString *mapStyle = @"document.getElementById('mapid').style.margin = 'auto';";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyleVertical];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyleHorizontal];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:mapStyle];
```

Hope it will helps you.....

Comment: Thanks for the code, at first usage it still only centers horizontally. I will mess around with it today and see if I can get it to work. Thanks again.

Comment: This one got me the closest, though I still haven't completely solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Keep everything in a `table` and then align the table cells.

CSS

```
td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

or

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">Text</td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I used this solution but needed to add  `<body style="margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;"> <table height="100%">` to ensure the table fit the webview frame vertically

Answer (score 2):

Vertical centering:

```
CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize;
CGFloat d = contentSize.height/2 - webView.center.y;
[webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, d) animated:NO];
```