# How to center a small size svg icon in a larger size webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, webview

I am using a Webview to load svg icons in my app. It works well with big images by using scalesPageToFit property. Now I am facing issues when using small size icons to fit in webview frame.

e.g. -
WebView size - 150w*150h
Icon dimension - 30*30

In this situation, icons align to the left top position of the webview. Is there any suggestion to center this in the web view or to enlarge it within webview frame? Any suggestion?

```
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"...badge.svg"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0];
    [self.menuView.webView loadRequest:request];
    self.menuView.webView.delegate = self;
```

//Delegate method

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
CGSize contentSize = webView.scrollView.contentSize; 
CGSize webViewSize = webView.bounds.size; 
CGFloat scaleFactor = webViewSize.width / contentSize.width;
webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scaleFactor;
webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = scaleFactor;
webView.scrollView.zoomScale = scaleFactor;
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you adding image in webview??

Comment: @nikdange_me Please check the above code.

Comment: ok .. checking @user1591698

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
NSString *bodyStyleVertical = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.verticalAlign = 'middle';";
NSString *bodyStyleHorizontal = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign = 'center';";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyleVertical];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyleHorizontal];
```

Comment: Thanks @nikdange_me, I have tried the above code, but it's not working.

Comment: did you got solution? @user1591698

Comment: No! I think I need to ask web team to update svg images as larger and centered. Do u have any other solutions. I tried the svgKit library but not working properly for some images.

Comment: hi @user1591698, i gave above answer refering from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741558/how-do-i-center-the-contents-of-a-webview-in-ios-vertically-and-horizontally, it should work as they stated. Well considering your UIWebView displays web content, ask web team for help!! :(

Comment: Ask them to add "center" allginment in css, rather than resizing!

Comment: Ok sure, I will ask them to  add "center" allginment. Thanks a lot @nikdange_me